# Retrieve data from two mysql table and return single result

Tags: mysql, select, join, union

I have two mysql tables such as

countriesRanking table

```
country, clicks
-------  -----
0         657  
1         3300
2         9050
```

clickTable table

```
id, name,    clicks,  deviceid, country
-- ------    ------   --------  -------
0   player1  33       uniqueid1  0
1   player2  665      uniqueid2  2 
2   player3  88       uniqueid3  18
3   player4  5000     uniqueid4  2
```

I want to retrieve a click value from countriesRanking table where the country is specified and the click value from clickTable where the deviceid is specified.

Something like

```
SELECT clicks FROM clicksTable WHERE deviceid='$deviceid' UNION SELECT clicks FROM countriesRanking WHERE country='$country'
```

So if deviceid is uniqueid4 and country is 2, this will return

```
5000, 9050
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ct.clicks fromClicks, cr.clicks fromCountry
FROM clicksTable ct 
LEFT JOIN countriesRanking cr ON ct.country = cr.country 
WHERE ct.deviceid='uniqueid4' AND ct.country = 2;
```

Check this link [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58f376/2)

**OUTPUT**

```
| FROMCLICKS | FROMCOUNTRY |
----------------------------
|       5000 |        9050 |
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT clicks FROM clicksTable ct
join countriesRanking cr on cr.country=ct.country

WHERE deviceid='$deviceid' and cr.country='$country'
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to retrieve a click value from countriesRanking table where the
>   country is specified and the click value from clickTable where the
>   deviceid is specified.

Like this:

```
SELECT clicks 
FROM clicksTable 
WHERE deviceid = 'uniqueid4' 
UNION ALL
SELECT clicks 
FROM countriesRanking 
WHERE country = 2;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58f376/1)

This will give you:

```
| CLICKS |
----------
|   5000 |
|   9050 |
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is correct but you have misspelled your Table Name `clickTable`. You wrote `clicksTable` instead.